# Enum values naming

Tags: java, enums, naming-conventions, naming

I am a Java developer trying to have grasp over the best clean code practices. Today, I had an argument with my colleague about enum naming. Please, share your views on this topic.

What I belive, is that the enum values' name, should be a parto of the Java code and stay consistent with the code base. Name, has to be understandable and to-the-point with what it does represent. It has to map 1:1 with the values in every possible way... BUT the name, does not have to be value.

So, let's assume we have a given set of horribly named columns:

- grapescountscolumnofinttype
- secondlongernameofdoubletype
- someveryfunkycolumnamewithsomeannotation.

If we'll make an enum "ColumnNames", my idea of clean code is to make those as readable as possible, so:

- GRAPES_COUNT
- SECOND
- VERFY_FUNKY

And keep the real column name as the "value" (used with this.getColumnName() or whatever)

According to my colleague, if we are enumerating the columns, then the name should match the column name. Otherwise, we are not enumerating the columns, but something that is mapped to/from the columns, and then the enum should not be named "TableColumns".

Any thoughts on what is the best, cleanest way of naming enums?

@Edit: adding example code

Very ugly SQL:

```
create table table ( grapescountscolumnofinttype number not null,
  secondlongernameofdoubletype number not null,
  someveryfunkycolumnamewithsomeannotation number not null);
```

Convert to clean Java code:

```
private enum TableColumn {
  GRAPESCOUNTSCOLUMNOFINTTYPE,
  SECONDLONGERNAMEOFDOUBLETYPE,       
  SOMEVERYFUNKYCOLUMNAMEWITHSOMEANNOTATION 
}
```

vs

```
private enum TableColumn {
  GRAPES_COUNTS("grapescountscolumnofinttype"),
  SECOND("secondlongernameofdoubletype"),
  VERY_FUNKY("someveryfunkycolumnamewithsomeannotation")
...

private String value;
  String getColumnName() { 
    return value;
  } 
}
```

Comment: Why would you even make an `enum` out of "ColumnNames". A name is not a true constant.

Comment: First of all: you would read about Java naming conventions. So "_" is a no go, unless for SOME_CONSTANT for example. And instead of lengthy talking about ideas, you better put down some examples in full code. But even then your question is probably too broad/opinionated ... thus not fitting.

Comment: @Kayaman What do you mean, that the name is not a constant? From the point of view of java code, DB column names do not change. And we're using those column names in the mapping of the DB tables (select statements and so on...).

Comment: @GhostCat I whout, that the uppercase in understood. The enum values are of course in upper case, as in most constant-like data.

Comment: Sounds to me like a bunch of string constants of the form `public static final String XXX_COL_NAME = "xxxColName"` would be just fine for this purpose.  What more would an enum  do for you?

Comment: But DB column names *do* change, in which case the second option would be more resilient as you'd only need to change the enum values. The example is a bit poor however, since if you're seriously manually mapping db columns to Java code, then you're not spending your time wisely.

Comment: @Kevin Anderson I ma sticking to rules from "Clean Code" by Robert C. Martin (J3: Constants versus Enums) and use enums for closed sets of values.

Comment: @Kayaman It is a big system that is using a framework, without this functionality. DB mappings HAVE to be done by the developers in the matching classes. Yeas, I would prefer something more modern and flexible, but no way around it. Security and cost reasons.

Comment: Hint: read a bit how formatting code here. You dont use ">" for that.

Comment: Fair enough, then.  As for the names of the enum constants, it's really your choice.  But do think about having to learn a new set of "Java"  column names and about mentally switching back and forth between the  "Java" names and the "real" names (especially when reading the error log when debugging a bad query...) If those thoughts fill you with dread, use ugly enum names that vary little, if at all, from the ugly real column names.  If none of that scares you, or you welcome the challenge, go crazy with fancy new abbreviated names.

Answer (score 0):

> What I belive, is that the enum values' name, should be a parto of the Java code and stay consistent with the code base. Name, has to be understandable and to-the-point with what it does represent. It has to map 1:1 with the values in every possible way

**(1)** I'd agree with that.

> BUT the name, does not have to be value.

**(2)** I think this is also true. One can infer this from the fact that you can use `int`s or strings that are not valid java names for values of enums. So, this statement is true, unless java language is inconsistent with it's intentions witch I don't think is the case here.

> If we'll make an enum "ColumnNames", my idea of clean code is to make those as readable as possible
>
> [...]
>
> And keep the real column name as the "value"

Now, this is an interesting part that can be interpreted in more then one way.

**(A)** From design standpoint it is a good idea if your intent is to make this enum an expression of mapping between java code and database schema. This implies dependency between specific piece of java code and that db schema.

**(B)** If your intention for this enum is being a part of your core business model, this is a bad idea, since implied dependency to db schema makes your core model dependent on it (unless this db schema is inherent part of business model by design, which is possible but probably not the case here).

> According to my colleague, if we are enumerating the columns, then the name should match the column name.

I would not agree with that because of (1), regardless of whether (A) or (B) is true.

> Otherwise, we are not enumerating the columns, but something that is mapped to/from the columns, and then the enum should not be named "TableColumns".

In case (A) is true I would agree with this and also I would agree that simply  "TableColumns" does not reflect the intent and implications good enough here. The reason is that implicit dependency (mapping) to specific db schema/table is not expressed. However, if you place that enum in appropriate namespace (package), like `com.appname.schemaname.tablename.TableColumns` or simply `com.appname.db.tablename.TableColumns` this should be enough. This way the implicit dependency is expressed explicitly in package structure and more visible and alarming if you try to use it as a part of business model.

In case (B) is true, I would also agree but in this case naming is not really a problem, hidden dependency to db schema is.

> Any thoughts on what is the best, cleanest way of naming enums?

Summarizing what I said above I would suggest:

- use established naming conventions for your java identifiers, do not leak specifics (like literal specific db names) into identifiers (see (1))
- is is ok to use enums not only as a closed sets of constants, but also as a sets of "mappers". This is a feature, not abuse (see (2)). Be aware that this may introduce some implicit dependencies though
- use naming to support distinction between core business model and specifics (or, in general, any contexts whose dependencies on one another should be controlled), namespaces are good aid in this

Answer (score 0):

So with the change in enums in JDK 6 there hasn't been an update to the naming standards applied and everything you read or come across will assume standard JDK 1.5 static naming. Underscores and Capitals Only. This includes the squid reference and the rest.
This is the accepted answer.

But I find/feel that this is simply not the case, there needs to be a clear and definitive separation between basic static types and complex enums types since JDK 6, and I use the naming convention to highlight this.

Camel case for enums.

```
private static final String BASIC_STATIC_TYPE;

enum EnumType
{
One,Two,Three,Four("OptionalChange");

public String toString()
{
return data == null ? name() : data;
}
}
```

This allows proper highlighting and syntax handling, and instantly tells the developer that this is not an primitive type (static finals) but an object reference in the MetaSpace with a primitive pointer. 
Code becomes cleaner without having to investigate the static type to find any methods/if it is a basic primitive.

This is one basic rule that I will break without feeling bad at all. I WANT to know the difference between static and enums by looking at the name, not by inspecting the reference.

Using enums that have numerical references, I prefix with a $